# Different network IO in dstat and netstat command

Tags: command-line, networking

I want to get total network I/O statistic. Using `dstat -n` command I got this output:

```
-net/total-
 recv  send
   0     0 
7334B 7380B
7084B 6948B
7411B 6672B
7030B 6828B
7130B 6606B
```

But using the command `sudo netstat` command I got this output:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 kafka1:37530            kafka2:9092             ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    264 kafka1:ssh              192.168.1.110:56686     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 kafka1:9092             kafka2:55146            ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 kafka1:9092             kafka3:46216            ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 kafka1:49042            kafka3:9092             ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 kafka1:58414            zookeeper1:2181         ESTABLISHED
```

Why the output of `dstat` is much bigger than (aggregate)output of `netstat`? Which one are real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `netstat` does.

`netstat` lists open net ports/streams/sockets and active connections. While that is IO related it does not count send/received bytes.

I don't know what you mean with *aggregate* output but the numbers after your hostnames *kafka1* and *kafka2* are ports, not bytes. The only thing it can do which might give you an insight in throughput is count packets.

If you mean **Recv-Q** and **Send-Q**

the man page says this :

**Recv-Q**
      *Established*: The count of bytes not copied by the user program connected to this socket.
*Listening*: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the current syn backlog.

**Send-Q**
*Established*: The count of bytes not acknowledged by the remote host.
*Listening*: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the maximum size of the syn backlog.

Comment: And the `Recv-Q`/`Send-Q` columns are, well, queues - the count of bytes not yet acknowledged.

Comment: Thanks, By `aggregate` I meant aggregate of all send and receive column values. So the `dstat` output is more realistic?

Comment: @muru exactly, the man page says this : **Recv-Q**
      *Established*: The count of bytes not copied by the user program connected to this socket.  *Listening*: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the current syn backlog.

   **Send-Q**
       *Established*: The count of bytes not acknowledged by the remote host.  *Listening*: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the maximum size of the syn backlog.

Comment: @soheil, netstat does not have any *Send or receive columns* ! The *Recv-Q* and *Send-Q* columns are somehting differnt entirely ! I will update my answer